# Internet Information Services (IIS) Web Site Slow Startup

Tags: iis

I have tried to minimize the startup time of our web site on Windows Server 2022 and IIS, but it still takes about 20–30 seconds to start occasionally. My application pool's advanced settings are the following:

[image: Settings]

I've tried to put Start Mode to AlwaysRunning and Idle Time-out Action to Suspend, but it has not removed the behaviour. Perhaps it's because of Recycling? The recycling settings are as follows:

[image: Recycling]

Is there a way to start the web site without the occasional 20-30 second delay?

Comment: Are you sure is not your site the problem? Create a plain html web site and put it under IIS and see how it behaves. Uninstall and reinstall IIS would be my next step.

Comment: Hmm... It might be also the SQL Server connection. I have SQL Server Express 2022 installed.

Comment: Like the other comment indicated, you didn't perform much troubleshooting yet. BTW, modern server administrators tend to use tools like Splunk to monitor all kinds of performance metrics so that they can easily find culprits (sudden CPU/disk IO spikes) via correlation. That might get you started.

Comment: According to your description, this problem seems to occur intermittently? If this is the case, after using tools to try to narrow down the scope of the problem, and if the problem still cannot be solved, I recommend that you open a [support ticket](https://support.microsoft.com/).

Comment: It can also be an occassional DDoS attack, based on our logs.

Comment: If this the case, you may need a commercial firewall, or cloud based services such as CloudFlare.